# add check boxes dynamically, js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create check boxes in for each row created dynamically. the code below is how I am creating a table. help will be greatly appreciated. Info: I am getting values of org from DB and publishing those values to a table.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('orgtable');

for (var i = 0; i < (orgvalues.length); i = i + 1) {

  var row = table.insertRow(-1);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);



  cell1.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">' +
    name + '</span>';

  cell1.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">' +
    phone + '</span>';


}
```

Comment: The last two lines of the code are identical, is this intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

```
var table = document.getElementById('orgtable');

for (var i = 0; i < (orgvalues.length); i = i + 1) {

  var row = table.insertRow(-1);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);



  cell1.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">' +
    name + '</span>';

  cell2.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">' +
    phone + '</span>';

  cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="yourCheckBoxId" value="yourCheckBoxVal">';


}
```

Comment: Awesome Sergio, worked great. Thankssssssssssss a lot for great effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can create checkbox via Javascript:

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
cell1.appendChild(checkbox);
```